# How to return a DATETIME in those formats

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a field on a MySql table with DATETIME data, and I'd like to select these data in some formats.

For example, I'd like to extract `2011-04-02 00:30:02` it in these ways :

1. 02/04/2011 - 00:30:02
2. 02/04 - 00:30:02
3. 02/04/2011
4. 00:30:02

using only MySql instruments.

Is it possible? Can you give to me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select date_format(date_column, '%d/%c/%Y - %H:%i:%s');

for a list of all the modifiers see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do it using the `DATE_FORMAT` mysql function

Answer (score 2):

Please check MySQL's [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.